# C++ android assetmanager reads files from app internal directory

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-assetmanager

I use AssetManager in C++ code to load my assets. But if there exists file with the same name in app internal directory AssetManager check it first and load it.

Is it possible to set AssetManager to avoid files in internal app dir and check only assets files?

UPD: I was wrong. AssetManager works normally.

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior for Java and NDK. Both use [AssetManager class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp) under the hoods. For [earlier versions of AssetManager.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/libs/utils/AssetManager.cpp), **AssetManager::open()** works the same.

It is, theoretically, possible to tweak AssetManager behavior (after all, [AssetManager.addAssetPaths()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#728) is **public**, and can be fetched via reflection), but there is no documented way to do this, which means that you cannot know if your hack will work on the next version of Android, or on some vendor's custom version of the system.

I would recommend not to do such tricks. <s>Much safer to check if the same file exists in internal directory, and delete or rename it, if necessary.</s> But anyways, the asset manager does not normally read from the internal files directory for the app.

Comment: Thank your very much. Your answer is very clean and helpful.

Comment: But now I have a problem: your observation does not reproduce here. Maybe you could show your code? Maybe this happens on certain platforms?

Comment: Yeah. Just have a look to this file in my repo. https://bitbucket.org/akk0rd87/akk0rdsdk/src/c14738567735457e9e1bd603a576648d6bf0be2d/framework/platforms/android/android_wrapper.cpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default  GetAsset2Buffer procedure

Comment: In my experiment, I could not change the result of **AAsset_read()** by adding files to internal dir.

Comment: I use this code to create file https://pastebin.com/7THK5U09  I don't really understnand where it creates file,  but AssetManager shows me it when I expect my asset file with the same name but another text.

Comment: According to source code [SDL_rwops.c](https://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/src/file/SDL_rwops.c) of SDL_RWFromFile it uses FILE *fp = fopen(file, mode); at first

Comment: So far so good. But how do you know it overrides  AAsset_read() ?

Comment: Sorry. I was mistaken, There is an miskate on my test case. It seems to be AssetsManager really read only from assets. Thank you very much.

Comment: It doesn't, as you can see in the sources. It looks for system assets, and from some 'overlays', and from **ANDROID_ROOT** - but it does not normally read from app internal files.